# Is memory leak unavoidable in C

Tags: c, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

There are many memory leak bug in our company's codes and normally our solution is "Reading the Codes" though we have tools to found memory leak's position. So I am wondering is memory leak unavoidable in C or it is not worth to do garbage collection to sacrifice system's performance.

Comment: Of course is avoidable.

Comment: "is memory leak unavoidable" - No. Counterexample, program that prints "hello world" :)

Comment: Memory leaks are essentially always avoidable.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler It doesn't. "Not unavoidable" is "avoidable" (or I misunderstand my comment :/ )

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: `while(1) { new BYTE; cout << "Hello World"; } // obviously...` :)

Comment: Too late in the day...my bad.

Answer (score 0):

It is always possible to avoid memory leaks, it's just that it can be difficult to do so when doing manual memory management. As programs grow complex it becomes harder to do memory management correctly. That is why you see many larger project implement some kind of automatic or semi automatic memory management. For instance GCC has a garbage collector, as has open source web browsers like Firefox and Chrome (I'm sure the closed source web browsers has it as well but it's not so easy to tell).

It is important to not that automatic memory management does not remove all memory leaks. Data can still be retained unnecessarily. But automatic memory management makes things easier and helps avoid errors like freeing memory twice or referencing already freed memory.